# Advice on typography and background image

Tags: css, background

I have a blog and i would like to ask anyone CSS savvy for advice on some changes.

http://fornuftfu.se/category/blogg/

1. Better Typography for the blog articles
2. Is the design too dull? Would a background image be good, and in that case what?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is a pretty broad question for StackExchange but I'll venture some quick feedback for you.

The typography isn't bad but it is dull. Try skipping Helvetica and going for a little modern web typography. Get your feet wet with the free Google Webfonts to differentiate from the hoards of sites who use Helvetica or (God forbid) Arial. If you're going for a minimalist look, find one family that has multiple weights to serve for heads and text (Lato is a good option). If you'd like a little more nuanced look, find a display face (a serif like Merriweather would work) and a text face (a sans, maybe Lato again).

Fonts.com is also offering free webfont accounts for smaller sites as well. Lots to choose from there.

Comment: Sounds very interesting. Could i ask you for help as how to integrate the webfonts to my site? I am familiar with CSS.

Comment: Oh i got it. Fairly easy. Thanks Google and big thanks to @plainclothes. Have a look again and tell me what you think. Is it going in the right direction? (I will change the font in the logo to match the webfont from google that i use as titles.)

Comment: Yeah, it's very easy to integrate. Thanks to Google, indeed!   You're site is looking more personal already. One other small but critical thing that is making your site feel a little corporate is the color palette. Blue and grey can be a lifeless combo. Try infusing the site with color. To get you thinking, browse around [Colour Lovers](http://www.colourlovers.com/) and find or build a palette you like.

Comment: Again, thanks for the tip. I found some similar color schemes and i think its a bit happier already. What do you think?

Comment: Looking good! Watch the current page highlight in the nav -- the contrast is very slight.

Answer (score 0):

Solid color backgrounds in web design are more preferred these days. They look much cleaner, and don't distract from the content.

I think white is fine, but some other light or dark, non-bright color would work as well.

As for the typography for the blog, one would need to specify which part. Are you talking about the title, headers, or the body text? They're all using a different font.

Comment: Im talking about the whole site. All of them. What do you think should be done to make it look more appealing?